# MediaPlayer Listview onItemClick not playing

Tags: android, listview, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Trying to make a MediaPlayer work on with a ListView however it doesn't seem to play when I press the item on the ListView. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great. Kinda new to this sorry if its obvious.

```
 public class soundboard2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

private int lastTopValue = 0;

private ImageView backgroundImage;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private String[] mFragmentTitles;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewsound);

    final MediaPlayer sound01 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound01);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mFragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fragments);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mFragmentTitles);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    // inflate custom header and attach it to the list
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_header, mDrawerList, false);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

    // we take the background image and button reference from the header
    backgroundImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.listHeaderImage);
    mDrawerList.setOnScrollListener(this);

            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {
            if (mDrawerList.getItemAtPosition(position)=="Player") {
                try {
                    sound01.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound01.start();
                sound01.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    @Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    backgroundImage.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
    if (lastTopValue != rect.top) {
        lastTopValue = rect.top;
        backgroundImage.setY((float) (rect.top / 2.0));
    }
}

}
```

Strings

```
   <string-array name="fragments">
    <item>Player</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
      </string-array>
```

Comment: Check your `if` condition. More on string comparison [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Yes I definitely think its to do with the if condition but not sure how to fix it even after looking at that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of things going wrong here, but I'll point out two things:

You need to [prepare](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()) your media before it can be started.  You probably don't want to wait until the last second to create and prepare the media before playing it.

You're creating a MediaPlayer in your onCreate but aren't doing anything with it.

Perhaps also consider instead using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) which is more appropriate for shorter clips that need to play very quickly in response to events.

Comment: Okay so I've changed it so I'm using the MediaPlayer from the onCreate, however it still doesn't play. Really want to use the MediaPlayer.

Comment: I also have no idea if the media is something that's playable by MediaPlayer.  You might also want to check out the media compatibility matrix. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: It definitely is as I've used it in a similar app with MediaPlay that used buttons instead of listview.